# Can I place the result into an int variable using either atof or atoi?

Tags: c, integer, atoi, atof

In c: Given the following code

```
int a;
char word[]=<some string>
```

Is there a difference between?

```
a = atoi(word) 
a = atof(word)
```

Comment: Did you try what happens if `<some string>` is a number that does not fit into any integer variable?

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` returns integer type, `atof` returns `double`.

So in the `atof` scenario you are additionally converting the temporary `double` into your `int`

Comment: Thank you.
But does the conversion make a difference in the end point? I mean other than the fact that there's a conversion, is there a difference between the two scenarios?

Comment: @Niv Given that this already is rather different, what would you consider to be a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

But the compiler will emit warnings. See below:

[image]

It tells you what will happen.

All double or float values will be truncated (not rounded).

See the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
 
    int i1{};
    int i2{};
    int i3{};
    char s1[] = "42";
    char s2[] = "42.1";
    char s3[] = "42.9";

    i1 = std::atof(s1);
    i2 = std::atof(s2);
    i3 = std::atof(s3);

    std::cout << s1 << "\t--> " << i1 << '\n'
        << s2 << "\t--> " << i2 << '\n'
        << s3 << "\t--> " << i3 << '\n';
}
```

If you want to get rid of the warnings and be more clean, you need to add a cast statement. Like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {

    int i1{};
    int i2{};
    int i3{};
    char s1[] = "42";
    char s2[] = "42.1";
    char s3[] = "42.9";

    i1 = static_cast<int>(std::atof(s1));
    i2 = static_cast<int>(std::atof(s2));
    i3 = static_cast<int>(std::atof(s3));

    std::cout << s1 << "\t--> " << i1 << '\n'
        << s2 << "\t--> " << i2 << '\n'
        << s3 << "\t--> " << i3 << '\n';
}
```

There will be no compiler warning:

[image]

Program output will be:

[image]